# Comparing number of files with an integer nto working - bash script

Tags: bash

I'm writing a bash script to process files using FFMpeg, depending on the number of files.

I'm writing an if / elif statement to check for how many files there are that match a string, but first taking away part of the end of the string. The comparison doesn't seem to work, I've tried == and -eq. Not sure of a better to do this

```
#!/bin/bash
#Generate Quads from 4 video files, Trio from 3 and duo from 2

#InputVariables
inputpath=$( pwd | awk -F/ '{ print $0"/" }' )
outputpath=$( pwd | awk -F/ '{ print $0"/" }' ) #TEMP TEST OUTPUT
#outputpath=$( pwd | awk -F/ '{ print "/"$2"/projects/"$5"/Library/Ref/ProcessedWitcam/"$6"/" }' )

#Command Start
if [ "$( echo $inputpath | grep -F witcam )" ]; then
    #Create only 1 instance of this script to avoid clashes
    if [ ! "$(ls /var/run/ | fgrep -i quadGen.pid)" ]; then
        yes no | nice -n 15 touch /var/run/wrangling/quadGen.pid
        echo "PID created"
        for videofile in $(find *_1_BTC.mp4 -type f); do
            if [ "$(ls $outputpath | fgrep -i ${videofile%_1_BTC.mp4}.mp4)" ]; then
                echo "Converted $videofile Already"
            else
                echo find "${videofile%_1_BTC.mp4}"* | wc -l
                if [ "find ${videofile%_1_BTC.mp4}* | wc -l" == 5 ]; then
                    echo "QUAD GEN"
                    timecode=$( ffmpeg -i "$videofile" 2>&1 | awk '$1 ~ /^timecode/ {print $NF}' | uniq  )
                    ffmpeg -i ${videofile%_1_BTC.mp4}_2.mxf -i $videofile -i ${videofile%_1_BTC.mp4}_3.mxf -i ${videofile%_1_BTC.mp4}_4.mxf -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]hstack[top]; [2:v][3:v]hstack[bottom]; [top][bottom]vstack,format=yuv420p[v]"  -map "[v]"  -ac 2 -flags global_header -timecode $timecode -c:v libx264  $outputpath/${videofile%_1_BTC.mp4}.mp4
                elif [ "find ${videofile%_1_BTC.mp4}* | wc -l" == 4 ]; then
                    echo "TRIO GEN"
                    timecode=$( ffmpeg -i "$videofile" 2>&1 | awk '$1 ~ /^timecode/ {print $NF}' | uniq  )
                    ffmpeg -i ${videofile%_1_BTC.mp4}_2.mxf -i $videofile -i ${videofile%_1_BTC.mp4}_3.mxf -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v][2:v]hstack=inputs=3[v]"  -map "[v]"  -ac 2 -flags global_header -timecode $timecode -c:v libx264  $outputpath/${videofile%_1_BTC.mp4}.mp4
                elif [ "find ${videofile%_1_BTC.mp4}* | wc -l" == 3 ]; then
                    echo "DUO GEN"
                    timecode=$( ffmpeg -i "$videofile" 2>&1 | awk '$1 ~ /^timecode/ {print $NF}' | uniq  )
                    ffmpeg -i ${videofile%_1_BTC.mp4}_2.mxf -i $videofile  -filter_complex "hstack" -ac 2 -flags global_header -timecode $timecode -c:v libx264  $outputpath/${videofile%_1_BTC.mp4}.mp4
                else
                    echo "Error: incorrect number of files"                 
                fi
            fi
        done
        yes no | nice -n 15 rm -f /var/run/wrangling/quadGen.pid
    fi
fi
```

This part:

```
echo find "${videofile%_1_BTC.mp4}"* | wc -l
```

This works correctly as I get a value back, I can't figure out how to compare it correctly

Comment: Are you sure it works correctly with the `echo` at the beginning?

Comment: You're right it doesn't! the value is wrong that it spits out. using your other comment, it worked fine. removed this test line. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double quotes introduce a string, not a command to run. Don't use them.

Use command substitution instead:

```
if [ $(find ${videofile%_1_BTC.mp4}* | wc -l) == 5 ]; then
```

You can use both `==` and `-eq` here: `==` compares strings, `-eq` compares integers.

Comment: Thanks. Frustrating that is was something that small! Appreciate the help, it worked straight away